# How to set association checkboxes to true by default in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I want to check my association checkboxes by default. I tried by setting the checked attribute to an array of plucked Company IDs.

```
= f.association :selected_companies, label_method: :name, as: :check_boxes, collection: Company.order(:name), :checked => Company.pluck(:id)
```

This seems to work, but when there are form field errors, the checkboxes are reset on the next request. I'd like to persist the users choice in these cases.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change your view to `checked: @company_ids` and then in your controller set that to `Company.pluck(:id)` in your `edit` action, but to `@your_main_object.selected_company_ids` in your `update` action.